# clearing the image in a picturebox

Tags: vb.net

'i using this code in the piicturebox1_paint

```
myusercolor=(sysytem.drawing.color.black)
myalpha=100
using g as graphics=graphics.fromimage(picturebox1.image)
    g.clear(color.white)
    dim currentpen as object=new pen(color.fromargb(myalpha,myusercolor),mypenwidth)
    g.drawpath(ctype(currentpen,pen),mousepath)
end using

'using in the form_load '
picturebox1.image=new bitmap(.....)

'in the clearbutton_click '
picturebox1.image=nothing
```

by this code i have a problem that when i click the clear button the picturebox is cleared.but in the picturebox's mouseover the last drawn picture will appear.so i cant draw a new image ..

Comment: anyone knows please answer for me.thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're drawing in the Picturebox1_paint event? This will fire every time the control is affected by such things as moving the form or in this case a mouse moving over it.
You should be drawing outside that event, but where depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's a guess, but I think that `mousepath` contains the "drawing" that the user has made. When initializing a new image (probably in the `clearbutton_click` event handler) you will also need to clear that data:

```
If Not mousepath Is Nothing Then
    mousepath.Dispose()
End If
mousepath = new GraphicsPath()
```

---

As a side note, not directly related to your question, I would suggest two improvements in how the `Pen` is handled. Look at the following two code lines (from your sample above):

```
dim currentpen as object=new pen(color.fromargb(myalpha,myusercolor),mypenwidth)
g.drawpath(ctype(currentpen,pen),mousepath)
```

This first creates a new `Pen` and stores it in the `object` variable `currentpen`. Since `currentpen` is declared as `object`, you need to cast it to `Pen` when passing it to `DrawPath`. If you instead declare `currentpen` as a `Pen` you don't need to do that cast. Also, `Pen` implements `IDisposable` so you should either call `Dispose` on it, or wrap it into a `using` block:

```
Using currentpen as Pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(myalpha,myusercolor),mypenwidth)
    g.drawpath(currentpen,mousepath)
End Using
```